# Consulta de clientes que han sido visitados por al menos un vendedor de cada grupo

Tags: sql

Tengo una tabla en la que almaceno los datos de clientes y el vendedor al que han visitado.
Necesito hacer una consulta que me devuelva solo los registros de clientes que hayan visitado al menos a un vendedor de cada grupo.

Estoy buscando con la clausula (idvendedor IN (2, 7, 13, 21, 47, 53))

Los ID 2, 7, 21 y 53 son de un grupo y 43, 47 de otro.

Alguna idea para no tener que filtrarlo con una tabla dinamica de excel?
gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Para hacer preguntas de SQL, es importante que incluyas la estructura de las tablas, así como el manejador de bases de datos que utilizas, ya que cada uno tiene sus variantes en la sintaxis. Lo que pides es algo sencillo pero requiere de más detalles para poder dar una solución de calidad.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo dos tablas de base con los siguientes campos:

```
Vendedor (idVendedor, Grupo)
VisitaCliente (idCliente, idVendedor)
```

Lo que haría falta para lograr lo que describes es:

- Hacer un join de la tabla de visitas con la de vendedores, a manera que podamos saber a qué grupo pertenece cada visita
- De estos registros, para quedarnos solo con uno de cada distinto grupo, nos valemos de la cláusula `distinct`
- De este resultado, contar cuántos registros hay para cada cliente, haciendo una agrupación por `idCliente`.
- Finalmente, valiéndonos de la cláusula `having` para filtrar los grupos, quedarnos solo con aquellos cuya cuenta de registros coincida con la cuenta de grupos que hay registrados en la tabla de vendedores.

Como siempre, el código habla mucho más que las palabras.

Esta consulta debería darte el resultado deseado:

```sql
select idCliente, COUNT(1) GruposVisitados
  from (select distinct VisitaCliente.idCliente, Vendedor.Grupo
          from VisitaCliente
               inner join Vendedor on VisitaCliente.idVendedor = Vendedor.idVendedor
       ) q0
 group by idCliente
having COUNT(1) = (select COUNT(1) from (select distinct Grupo from Vendedor) q1 )
```